# Divide int and store back into original variable

Tags: c, pointers

I have a function that does some stuff (that portion is irrelevant) then it sets a value called num, then prints that value. My issue is as a final step of my function before printing the value it must divide by 4. That is where I am hitting a snag... See below:

```
int *num = 0;

.
. //num is determined here...
.

num = num/4; // <-- My issue
printf("%d\n", num);
```

The error I get is:

```
error: invalid operands to binary / (have 'int *' and 'int')
```

Which, from so searching means I need to deference it like so:

```
num = (*num)/4;
```

Though this also does not work correctly (it doesn't give any errors, it actually puts my code into an infinite loop and Windows stops it). What I am trying to do is take the value stored at num (the address) and divide it by for and then set num value to that new value. But I see to be struggling with getting this work correctly.

Comment: Presumably, you should be using `*num /= 4;` if you want to divide the number that `num` points at by 4.  You also need to print `*num` or change the format to `”%p\n”` if you really want to print a pointer.  Another possibility is that you should define `int num = 0;` instead of defining a pointer.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler , using `int num = 0;` fixed my problems. Thank you.

Comment: @MicrosoftDave: If using `int num = 0;` fixed your problems, what was your original intent with `int *num = 0;` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num` is of type pointer. So `num = num /4`  ; is a very unlikely thing to do. It is not even allowed.

As per standard **6.5.5**`Each of the operands shall have arithmetic type.`(Multiplicative expression)

Compiler also tells you that thing `error: invalid operands to binary / (have 'int *' and 'int')`.

`/` takes two arguments. But compiler is looking at the operands and it sees that they are of type *. So it complains because it not allowed as oer standard.

`num =*num/4;` is basically assigning an integer result to a pointer variable. Which even though may not lead to desired behavior but allowed. (We also do `int *p =NULL`)

Comment: Okay, so I got it, turns out I should not have been defining it as a pointer. But just simply as `int num = 0`, from there using `num = num/4` works as expected. Thank you, Im still learning C and pointers have been tricky to keep track of.

Answer (score 0):

This statement below declares a pointer

```
int *num = 0;
```

meaning points to some memory where value is there;

This statement below is very interesting

```
.
. //num is determined here...
.
```

when you say num is determined here there are couple of ways to interpret this

is there an assignment to value as below in which case RHS must be value

```
*num = some value;
```

or assignment to pointer as below in which case RHS must be an address or pointer.

```
num = some address;
```

Finally when you do this, you are operating on pointer because `num` represents a pointer where as `*num` represents value and below statement is invalid for pointers as `Multiplication or Division of a pointer is not allowed in C`

```
num = num/4; // <-- My issue
```

also when you are printing here, you are basically printing the address of num than printing the value.

```
printf("%d\n", num);
```